# Disable "No matches found" text and autocomplete on select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

How do you disable the "No matches found" text on autocomplete on select2/Tagging Support?

This is what I have now:

```
$('#ProductDescriptions_30_keywords').select2({
        tags:[],
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        }
    );
```

But it still shows the "No matches found" message in autocomplete window. I would like to remove this.

Comment: There is not enough information for this to qualify as a question. Please take the time to write a clear question, and post your code. It would be very helpful if you also provide a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of your non-working code so we have a starting point to help you solve your question.

Comment: Unless the question has since been updated, it has more than adequate information (especially as I was looking for an answer to the exact same question). Thanks @simonadcock for the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I see what you're getting at... You want to hide the text that says "No matches found" if a user enters a value into that search field that doesn't exist in the list?

You can probably do that in CSS:

```
.select2-no-results {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Here's **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/8kRkc/)**.

Comment: This is no longer valid in Select2 4.0, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Comment: @guidod: It's a bit of a hack, but you could build a selector that exploits the fact that the "No results found" `li` does not have an `id` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/8kRkc/59/

Comment: this will hide other select2 dropdown options if you have another select2 dropdown on page

Answer (score 10):

Actually I was using the select2 v4 tags and the code below helped me :

```
 $(document).find(".email_contact_search").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    "language":{
      "noResults" : function () { return ''; }
    }
  });
```

I just made the noResults language string to none :

```
"language":{
          "noResults" : function () { return ''; }
        }
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3):

For select2 4.0 you can do

```
.select2-results__message {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.select2-results {
     display: none;
 }
```

**Just override this **

Answer (score 1):

For select 2 4.0 you can do

```
$('#id').select2({
   minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Version 4.0.13*. You can do either one below code

```
.select2-results__message {
    display:none !important;
}

*OR*

li.select2-results__message {
    display:none !important;
}

*OR*

.select2-results .select2-results__message {
    display:none !important;
}
```