# select2 - use as autocomplete textbox (even if not an option)

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I'm trying to use the select2 add-on as more of a textbox (compared to a dropdown) with autocomplete features. This means that if a user types something that is not in the list, I want this custom value to remain as the value for the form.

I've searched stackoverflow and found the following:

[Disable "No matches found" text and autocomplete on select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470917/disable-no-matches-found-text-and-autocomplete-on-select2)

[Select2, when no option matches, "other" should appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950117/select2-when-no-option-matches-other-should-appear)

Neither of them keep the "custom" value.

Answer (score 2):

You can add value of Search textbox as an option when there is change in value of Search box. 
To achieve whatever I said you will have to mess with original source code as I cannot see any event related to search text box in github. 
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

If you can change your preference from dropdown to tagging just check example named "auto tokenization" 
In same page.

Answer (score 0):

see proposed revision that will add this behaviour to select2:

https://github.com/clarkbox/select2/commit/48c8e8591081ccda5d0318efcf6761d1f1c0a573#diff-1fb8e09d75683cc4dd4a88850714595f