# Remove select2 no data found text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have made a select2 multi input in order to add tags. However, when I click on the input it shows no results found. Is there a better way to remove it instead of adding css?

I use select2 version `4.0.12`

https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags

css to remove it:

`.select2-results__option.select2-results__message`

Initialization:

```
$(()=>{
    $("#sel-inp").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [','],
        id: 'add_keywords',
        width: '100%'
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Old question, so I won't close it as a direct dupe, but this may contain your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18470917/519413

Comment: Okay but I don't want to apply this to all the inputs but to a specific one instead.

Comment: So make the selector specific to that element...?

Comment: Okay but your suggested link didn't work: `.select2-no-results {  display: none !important;}`

Comment: The approach is what you need to use. Amending it for your specific environment, I assumed, was just common sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution using `noResults` method.

```
 $("#mail_add_keywords").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    id: 'mail_add_keywords',
    width: '100%',
    "language": {
       "noResults": () => "Add Keywords"

    }
})
```